# Identity matrix times i

Tags: matrices, clifford-algebras

Why is the psuedoscalar in 5 dimensions the identity matrix?

In 3 dimensions its $\begin{pmatrix}
  i & 0  \\
  0 & i  
\end{pmatrix}$

In 3 dimensions when you multiply all 3 vectors (Pauli matrices) together you get the unit psuedoscalar. Multiplying a vector (Pauli matrix) times the psuedoscalar results in a bivector (quaternion)

$
\begin{array}{r|rrr|rrr|r}
{\color{red} {I_2}} &  
{\color{green} {\sigma_1}} & 
{\color{green} {\sigma_2}} &
{\color{green} {\sigma_3}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}}} & 
{\color{red} {i_2}} 
\\\hline
{\color{green} {\sigma_1}} & 
{\color{red} {I_2}} &  
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{-\hat{\jmath}}}} & 
{\color{green} {\sigma_2}} &
{\color{green} {-\sigma_3}} & 
{\color{red} {i_2}} &
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}}} 
\\
{\color{green} {\sigma_2}} &  
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{-\hat{\imath}}}} & 
{\color{red} {I_2}} &  
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}}} & 
{\color{green} {-\sigma_1}} &
{\color{red} {i_2}} &
{\color{green} {\sigma_3}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}}} 
\\
{\color{green} {\sigma_3}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}}} &  
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{-\hat{k}}}} & 
{\color{red} {I_2}}        &  
{\color{red} {i_2}} &
{\color{green} {\sigma_1}} &   
{\color{green} {-\sigma_2}} &
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}}} 
\\\hline
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}}} &
{\color{green} {-\sigma_2}} &
{\color{green} {\sigma_1}} &  
{\color{red} {i_2}} &
{\color{red} {-I_2}} &  
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{-\hat{\jmath}}}} & 
{\color{green} {-\sigma_3}} 
\\
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}}} & 
{\color{green} {\sigma_3}} & 
{\color{red} {i_2}} & 
{\color{green} {-\sigma_1}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{-\hat{k}}}} & 
{\color{red} {-I_2}} &  
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}}} & 
{\color{green} {-\sigma_2}}
\\
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}}} &  
{\color{red} {i_2}} &
{\color{green} {-\sigma_3}} &  
{\color{green} {\sigma_2}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{-\hat{\imath}}}} &  
{\color{red} {-I_2}} &  
{\color{green} {-\sigma_1}}
\\\hline
{\color{red} {i_2}} &
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}}} & 
{\color{blue} {\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}}} & 
{\color{green} {-\sigma_3}} &
{\color{green} {-\sigma_2}} &
{\color{green} {-\sigma_1}} & 
{\color{red} {I_2}} 
\end{array}  $

Identity matrix (scalar) is in red.

The Pauli matrices (vectors) are in green.

Quaternions (bivectors) are in blue.

Unit pseudoscalar is in red.

But when you go to 5 dimensions and use the Dirac matrices you get something totally different.

Multiplying any 2 vectors (Dirac matrices) results in a bivector as expected. But multiplying a bivector times a Dirac matrix results not in a trivector as expected but rather in another bivector.

And multiplying any 4 Dirac matrices results not in a quadvector as expeted but rather in a Dirac matrix (a vector).

Multiplying all 5 Dirac matrices result in the identity matrix instead of the pseudoscalar.

You can check my work here: https://math.wikia.com/wiki/Dirac_matrices#Alpha_multiplication_table and https://math.wikia.com/wiki/Pauli_matrices

Might take a minute to load though

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras#Unit_pseudoscalar

Apparently it's periodic. In seven Dimensions the pseudoscalar would be $i \cdot I$ again